# Redirecting to a blanck page /loginPost after fail in login

Tags: login

If my customer tries to login with a wrong password, he/she is getting redirected to a blank page with this URL: `.../index.php/customer/account/loginPost/`. I tried to change some things in `login.phtml` but I really don't know how to fix this.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: is compilation enable or not ?

Comment: Khoa: Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: It's not enabled. Should I enable it? It will fix that?

Comment: I enabled the compilation and didn't solved the problem

Comment: Anyone found any fix for this issue?